# background hover change on HTML button

Tags: html, css, sass

CSS hover only changes the background of the text, not the entire button background. Is there a way to change the entire background of the button on hover? I've tried making a container for the button and changing the background there but the background appears as a rectangle and my button is round.

```
<a href="google.ca">
   <button class="main-button">
      <span>CONTACT ME</span>
   </button> 
</a>


.main-button{
  border-radius:50px;
  border:3px solid $Green;
  overflow:hidden;
  color:$Green;
  background:transparent;
  width:20%;
  height:8%;
  :hover{
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    background:$Dark;
  }
  span{
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:120%;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to put a '&' before your ':hover'. Fixed your code:

```
.main-button{
 border-radius:50px;
 border:3px solid $Green;
 overflow:hidden;
 color:$Green;
 background:transparent;
 width:20%;
 height:8%;
 &:hover{  /* <-- HERE WAS THE MISTAKE */
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  background:$Dark;
 }
 span{
  font-weight:bold;
  font-size:120%;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
 }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jnzn22yb/

Comment: What does the & symbol do?

Comment: I could try to explain it by my own, but the SASS documentation is already written^^: [Take a look](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#parent-selector)